# cronjob excuted but no images show up in mail

Tags: php, html, cron

I have set up a cron job on my server and it is running everyday and sending out the mail. However on all the mails images are missing.

when I run the php file directly from website like this 
www.mysite.com/cronjobs/sendmail.php it runs fine. All mails are sent out too and all images show up.

Are images referenced different when run from a cronjob?

Or could it be they get blocked when run from a cronjob?

Could somebody please explain what could be wrong.

Comment: Most probably your image Paths are relative. Those get messed up in a cron. Use Absolute paths and try again.

Comment: ALWAYS use full path in cronjobs!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies. paths are indeed relative. Will try to change this and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated the problem seems to be in relative paths you use. If you want to keep using them attach all used images as attachments to the mail.

The second option is to use absolute paths. Btw don't forget to give your images folder read permissions.

Comment: will go for absolute paths. Gonna try that first. images folder has read permissions. They do come through when I run the php manualy.